Appdelegate function in iOS(swift-UIkit) is not called when clicked on universal links
I have added applinks: example.com in my Xcode entitlements
This his my My app-site-association which I uploaded in web https://<fully qualified domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association :
{
    "applinks": {
        "details": [
            {
                "appIDs": [
                    "ABCDEF.com.abcdef.example"
                ],
                "components": [
                    {
                        "/": "/service/test",
                        "comment": "Matches URL with a path /service/test"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "webcredentials": {
        "apps": [
            "ABCDEF.com.abcdef.example"
        ]
    }
}

My web credentials is working but not universal links
Below function is never called. I tried adding breakpoint and writing print statement
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool

If you use a scene delegate, use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3238059-scene otherwise use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application

@ClausJørgensen I followed this document for Supporting universal links in your app

@ClausJørgensen as I am using associated domains I followed apple documentation related to associated domains. Please have a look at the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains

First you need to check your Universal link Apple App Site Association(AASA). If your code is not triggering inside userActivity try validator first. And also your json looks wrong there is unnecessary comma inside appIDs.
Asa Validator: https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/
After that do not forget check NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
        
        if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb {
         
        }
    }

